# Ruby Rails Record Associations(has_many :through)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

Hi I am creating 3 models with ruby rails
But I have some problem.
Here's my model code

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pendings
    has_many :products, :through => :pendings
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pendings
  has_many :companies, :through => :pendings
end

class Pending < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I wanted make it company can have many Products through Pending vice versa, It worked well, but is there any way to set only 1 pending model between company and product.

[Here's my currently model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYDf6.png)

[I want to make it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6BXT.png)

Comment: What do you mean by **is there any way to set only 1 pending model between company and product** ?

Comment: for example, company has two pending belongs to same product. but I want make that only one pending model exists belongs to company and product...sry it is hard to explain.

Comment: If you want to keep only one pending per product/company, then you should use `has_one` association.

Comment: Thank you I will try. and I edited question please see the image what i attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: you could leave the association as is, but add the following validation to pending.rb

```
validates :company_id, uniqueness: {scope: :product_id}
```

see more here: [rails validation docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

This will ensure that you can only have one pending per company and product...but many pendings for the companies with regard to other products.